# Drawing with lines function in Android using Java

Tags: java, android, drawing

Ok, so I have a server (on computer) and the client (android phone).

I have set up a connection via socket, and I can draw on the server frame, and then show it on the clients screen.

This is what I'm sending:

```
 addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // save coord x,y when mouse is pressed
            startDrawing=true;
            oldX = e.getX();
            oldY = e.getY();
            try {
                if (s != null) {
                    mouseSend = new MouseData(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY, startDrawing, isDrawing, endDrawing);
                    out.writeObject(mouseSend);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // coord x,y when drag mouse
            currentX = e.getX();
            currentY = e.getY();
            isDrawing = true;
            startDrawing=false;
            endDrawing=false;

            if (g2 != null) {
                try {
                    // draw line if g2 context not null
                    g2.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
                    if(s!=null) {
                        mouseSend = new MouseData(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY, startDrawing, isDrawing, endDrawing);
                        out.writeObject(mouseSend);
                    }
                    // refresh draw area to repaint
                    repaint();
                    // store current coords x,y as olds x,y
                    oldX = currentX;
                    oldY = currentY;
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And here's what I receive on the client, and use that data to draw lines:

```
socket = new Socket("192.168.20.7",8080);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());


            while(in!=null) {

                mouseReceive = (MouseData) in.readObject();
                xReceive = mouseReceive.mouseX;
                yReceive = mouseReceive.mouseY;
                xNew = mouseReceive._nowX;
                yNew = mouseReceive._nowY;
                startDrawing = mouseReceive.startDrawing;
                isDrawing = mouseReceive.isDrawing;
                endDrawing = mouseReceive.endDrawing;

            }
```

And the draw function:

```
    public void drawPath() {


invalidate();

    if(startDrawing=true){
        testx=xReceive;
        testy=yReceive;
    }

    if(isDrawing=true) {
        drawCanvas.drawLine(testx, testy, xNew, yNew, drawPaint);
        invalidate();


        System.out.println(xReceive + " " + yReceive + " " + xNew + " " + yNew);
    }

    invalidate();
}
```

Now comes the problem. I want it to draw a path wherever the person on the server is drawing, and I'm trying to do it using lines. But right now it's creating dots and not connecting them properly. 
I've tried so many things, also tried using Path on canvas, but I couldn't get anything to work :(

It's starting to get frustrating so I thought I would go here to search for help.

I thought about connecting them via an array list and creating lines between the points, but I have no idea where to start :/

Please if someone could help me I'd appreciate it so much!

Here's a picture of what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: what about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline ?

Comment: I haven't used splines before, it looks a bit advanced compared to what I'm trying to achieve :P

Comment: If I replace my draw functon with public void drawPath() {

    invalidate();

        if(isDrawing=true) {
            drawCanvas.drawLine(testx, testy, xNew, yNew, drawPaint);
            testx = xNew;
            testy = yNew;
            invalidate();


            System.out.println(xReceive + " " + yReceive + " " + xNew + " " + yNew);
        }

        invalidate();
    }


It sort of works. It's smooth and no holes, but the problem here is that it's a continous path, I can't stop it or start a new :(
Image illustrating:
http://i.gyazo.com/8cef96c06cb9378a61af2f69f70d870c.png

Comment: Do you call the drawPath() from the UI thread and the network communication on a different thread?

Comment: No they are in the same class.

I haven't really learned much about threads, and I doubt I'm using it even though I should be.

I call my network communication in
public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

which is also probably wrong